# php export csv from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have script that should export .csv file from database. Problem is that it will save export to specific ($f) file but wont download correct file (script download empty file)

```
    <?php
//load the database configuration file
include '../secure/db_connect.php';

//get records from database

$sql_list = "SELECT * FROM `hakom` ORDER BY id DESC";
$sql_list_result = $mysqli->query($sql_list);



if($sql_list_result->num_rows > 0){
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = "members_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

    //create a file pointer
    $f = fopen('hakom_export.csv', 'w');

    //set column headers
    $fields = array('ID', 'MSISDN_');
    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

    //output each row of the data, format line as csv and write to file pointer
    while($row = $sql_list_result->fetch_assoc()){

        $lineData = array($row['ID'], $row['MSISDN_']);
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }

    //move back to beginning of file
    fseek($f, 0);

    //set headers to download file rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

    //output all remaining data on a file pointer
    fpassthru($f);
}
exit;

?>
```

i follow tutorial on [this page](https://www.codexworld.com/export-data-to-csv-file-using-php-mysql/)

Comment: Have you checked for errors? Either in the log or by switching on error messages?

Comment: sorry but dont know how to do that, i am new at php/sql

Comment: I guess you cannot write the file on server because of rights. Try wth `$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');` instead of use `'hakom_export.csv'`.

Comment: Switching error messages on, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thak you, i put 'php://memory' and it worked. I dont know how but before i try to use that and it give me some error in export. Now all working, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your opening the file for write only...

```
$f = fopen('hakom_export.csv', 'w');
```

from fopen manual page...

> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.

Change the mode to w+

```
$f = fopen('hakom_export.csv', 'w+');
```

> 'w+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the
>   beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the
>   file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
  <?php

// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM table');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);


?>
```